# How to use bootstrap after NuGet installed it on Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm a newbie to asp.net core and using NuGet install bootstrap package firstime. However, after I installed this package on Visual Studio Mac, I can't find any css/js files in my solution folder.

I'm using Visual Studio Mac 2019 and created a web app using asp.net core.

I expect I can find css/js files in solution folder, or I can reference any parameters in my razor pages.

Comment: The way using `Nuget` to manage the client dependencies doesn't work for `ASP.NET Core` any more. 

I would suggest you should use `npm` or `libman` to install the packages: 

1. using `npm install bootstrap` 
2. Or using `libman` to manage the client packages. For a GUI way, see https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/wiki/Using-LibMan-in-Visual-Studio

Comment: And see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.2